# Libgdx Объект timer срабатывает сразу

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, libgdx

В приложении есть два таймера. Первый после старта работает нормально, щелкает раз в секунду, отрабатывает игровую логику.

```
    GameTimer = new Timer();
    gtTask = new GameTimerTask();
    gtTask.setGame(this);

    GameTimer.schedule(gtTask, 0, 1000);
```

Пытаюсь запустить второй таймер

```
        KrabSupTimer = new Timer();
        KrabSupTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Определяем задачу
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                //  Вернем к жизни краба
                CatSupMan = false;
                KrabSupTimer.cancel();
            }
        }, 0L, 20L * 1000);
```

По идее должна выдерживаться пауза в 20 секунд. Но, почему-то переменная CatSupMan обнуляется моментально.

Вопрос, в чем может быть проблема?

З.Ы.Ж. Не может ли помочь переделка кода на использование ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Answer (score 2):

Если обратиться к официальным [докам](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), то увидим

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task,
        long delay,
        long period)
```

Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, ***beginning after the specified delay***. Далее опущено.

delay - отсрочка задания.

period - период выполнения.

У вас, как видно delay = 0.

Comment: Вчиталсв документация delay - интервал до первого запуска, period - интервал.